# How to get a list of country codes in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, countries

I wonder how to get list of country code [not country names] in WooCommerce?

I've gone through the WooCommerce docs but can't find the code. I know how to get the list of country names from WooCommerce but can't figure out how to get the codes

I am putting a country select box on a custom registration template. Where the select option value should be country code.

**Example**

```php
$all_countries = $countries_obj->countries; //Country Name array
$all_countries_code = ?????

foreach($all_countries as $ac){
    echo '<option selected value="[country_code]">'.$ac.'</option>';
}
```

Any help would be appreciated to get the country code array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WC()->countries->get_countries()` and then use the array key

So you get:

```php
// Get all countries key/names in an array:
$countries = WC()->countries->get_countries();

echo '<select name="countries">';

foreach ( $countries as $code => $country ) {
    echo '<option value="' . $code . '">' . $code . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

---

- `$countries` = countries keys/names in an array
- `$code` = country code (key)
- `$country` = country name

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get all countries key/names in an array:
$countries = WC()->countries->get_countries();

echo '<select name="countries">';

foreach ( $countries as $code => $country ) {
    echo '<option value="' . $code . '">' . $country . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```